# How can i install matlab without an install file?

Tags: installation, matlab

My matlab iso doesn't have the install file, only has a .exe file to install on windows platform, where can i find the install file?

i'm working with this instructions http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zndkhp2vLQ

sorry but i'm new in ask ubuntu and i can't show screenshot on this post

I'm working on ubuntu 11.10 and Matlab R2011B

*thanks for your patience*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That video demonstrates installing the Linux version of Matlab under Ubuntu. It sounds like you have the Windows version of Matlab, so this leaves you with following options:

- Get the Windows version of Matlab.
- Try running your copy of Matlab under Wine.

**OR**

- Install linux version of matlab. According to this [thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/285417) if you have purchased legally  you should get matlab for windows,linux and mac without any extra cost.

**OR**

- Install windows in virtualbox and use matlab in that.

A quick introduction to Wine is available [here](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/wine).

Comment: only i have the matlab for windows platform, i'll download matlab for unix platforms.

thank you